# Free hex file viewer

Tags: windows

What's the best free hex file viewer for windows?

Comment: Good list of hex editors http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) with the [HEX plugin](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=189927&package_id=222593).

Keith

Comment: I've tried this and it does a pretty good job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've found [XVI 32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) to be free handy tool.

Answer (score 1):

How about [HEdit](http://www.yurisw.com/HEdit.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I use [HHD's hex editor](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/Family/hex-editor.html).

Answer (score 1):

Editor for vim user [bvi](http://bvi.sourceforge.net/)

Good list of hex editors  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I last needed a hex editor, but back in the days, I always used WinHex: http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/

Answer (score 0):

[1Fh](http://www.4neurons.com/1Fh/) is a lightweight one that'll display all 256 characters, not just the printable ones.

Answer (score 0):

[PSCX](http://www.codeplex.com/Pscx) for PowerShell includes `Format-Hex` with quite a few options.